# I don't understand why I am getting the value of dob as an object when in use react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

when I console log  the value of dob, its an object instead of a string

**initial state**

```
const initialValues = {
    registrationForm: {
     
        dob: {
            elementType: 'date',
            elementConfig: {
                name: 'dob',
                required: true,
                placeholderText: 'Date of birth'
            },
            value: null,
        },
    },
   
}
```

**state***

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
```

**updateObject**

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
    return {
        ...oldObject,
        ...updatedProperties
    };
};
```

**handle change handler**

```
  const handleChange = (event, inputIdentifier, config) => {
      
      
        const updatedRegistrationForm = updateObject(values.registrationForm, {
            [inputIdentifier]: updatedFormElement
        });

        setValues({registrationForm: updatedRegistrationForm);


    };
```

**handle submit***

```
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const formData = {};
        for (let formElementIdentifier in values.registrationForm) {
            formData[formElementIdentifier] = values.registrationForm[formElementIdentifier].value;
        }

        console.log(formData)
    };
```

```
for (let key in values.registrationForm) {
        formElementsArray.push({
            id: key,
            config: values.registrationForm[key]
        });
    }
```

**form**

```
                 <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                
             
                            {
                                formElementsArray.slice(sliceStart, sliceNumber).map(({config, id}) => {
                         
                                    return <Input
                                        key={id}
                                        elementType={config.elementType}
                                        elementConfig={config.elementConfig}
                                        value={config.value}
                                        changed={(event) => handleChange(event, id)}/>

                                })
                            }


                </form>
```

**input**

```
const Input = ({
                   elementType,
                   elementConfig,
                   value,
                   changed,
                 
               }) => {
    let inputElement = null;

    switch (elementType) { 
        case ('date'):
            inputElement =
                <DatePicker
                    id={id
                    className='mb-3 form-control'
                    {...elementConfig}
                    selected={value}
                    onChange={changed}/>
            break;
      
    }
    

    return (

        <>
            {inputElement}
        </>


    );
};

export default Input;
```

**I was expecting something similar to this when I console log(Stringvale)**

dob: "2023-01-11T21:00:00.000Z"

**but I got this(an object)**

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just post the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <DatePicker
     id={id
     className='mb-3 form-control'
     {...elementConfig}
     selected={value}
     onChange={changed}/>
```

`onChange` in DatePicker returns a date object. You can use any date formatters to convert the date object to required format.

Update `changed` method to accept the date object, do the conversions like below.

```
const handleChange = (event, inputIdentifier, config) => {
  const updatedRegistrationForm = updateObject(values.registrationForm, 
    {
      [inputIdentifier]: updatedFormElement
    });

  if(inputIdentifier=="dob") {
    updatedFormElement.value=formatDate(date); //create some function to do the date formatting
  } else {
    updatedFormElement.value = event.target.value // for example
  // logic for non date inputs
  }

 setValues({registrationForm: updatedRegistrationForm);
};
```